# Google BigQuery: join on an join Alias

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i try to perform an join on a table that is the result of an other join. But i recieve the error: Table "join_1" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table). I bolded the Problem.
Thanks a lot in advance.

How can I qualify table join_1?
I edited the table, I hope that helps to understand the problem more. Thanks a lot, you guys reply that fast, you guys are awesome.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (

SELECT
  *
FROM
  `prod.box.records` AS records


LEFT JOIN 

  `prod.box.record_updates` as updates

USING
  (c2)

WHERE c11 ="view") AS join_1

INNER JOIN

(
  SELECT
    c1,
    c6,
    c2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      c1,
      IFNULL(c4,c3) AS c6,
      c2,
      c7
    FROM (
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        c4,
        c5
      FROM
        **join_1**)

    LEFT JOIN
(
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        MAX(c5) AS c5,
        "TRUE" AS c7
      FROM
        join_1
      GROUP BY
        c5,
        c2)
    USING
      (c2, c1, c5)
    GROUP BY
      c1,
        c6,
        c2,
      c7
    HAVING
      c7 = "TRUE")) AS status


USING
  (c2,
    c1)
```

...

Comment: you show a query with several joins. Your goal is not clear. There are 5 columns, but it is not clear what they mean, what the joins shall do.

Comment: Thanks for getting into my problem. The status part of (c1, c2,c5,c7) is a MAX Aggregation of datetime, grouped by date and id.  And the part with the columns (c1 to c5) is the status of the id, but i got 2 different status columns (c4,c3) and any status column can have a different mode. There are 3 modes possible. And the result should perform an inner join on the Left join of the tables records and records_updates. I hope that helps a bit. I have tried the solution but i got an Error, that he misses an ) at th end, but when I place the ), he doesn´t recognize any column anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my Problem, but I was only able to find it, because of your "with clause" hint, samuel. So, thanks a lot, Samuel.
But I will post the answer here, I have put all Joins into With clauses just the last one i did in the SELECT.

```
with 
join_1 as (
SELECT *
FROM
prod.box.records AS records
LEFT JOIN
prod.box.record_updates AS updates
USING
(c2)
WHERE c11 ="view"), status as (
SELECT
    c1,
    c6,
    c2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      c1,
      IFNULL(c4,c3) AS c6,
      c2,
      final_status
    FROM (
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        c4,
        c5
      FROM
        join_1)
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        c5,
        "TRUE" AS final_status
      FROM
        join_1
      GROUP BY
        c5,
        c2)
    USING
      (c2, c1, c5)
    GROUP BY
      c1,
        c6,
        c2,
      final_status
    HAVING
      final_status = "TRUE")

USING
  (c2,
    c1))
SELECT
  *
FROM join_1
INNER JOIN
status
USING
  (c2,
    c1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a subquery several time, please use the CTE `WITH` statement.

```sql
WITH
records as (Select 1 c2,1 c1,3 c3,4 c4,5 c5),
record_updates as (Select 1 c2,"view" c11),
join_1 as
(
SELECT * FROM records AS records
LEFT JOIN record_updates as updates
USING (c2)
WHERE c11 ="view"
)

Select * from join_1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    c1,
    c6,
    c2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      c1,
      IFNULL(c4,c3) AS c6,
      c2,
      c7
    FROM (
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        c4,
        c5
      FROM
        join_1)

    LEFT JOIN
(
      SELECT
        c1,
        c2,
        c5,
        "TRUE" AS c7
      FROM
        join_1
      GROUP BY
        c5,
        c2, c1)
    USING
      (c2, c1, c5)
    GROUP BY
      c1,
        c6,
        c2,
      c7
    HAVING
      c7 = "TRUE")) AS status


USING
  (c2,
    c1)
```